# Are Promises in JavaScript guaranteed to make progress even if they are not consumed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Say I create a `Promise` that represents the result of a `GET` request, but let it go out of scope without awaiting/using it. Am I guaranteed that the promise makes progress (i.e. the request happens) anyway? Or is it possible, that the garbage collector cleans it up before it is settled?

Comment: Promise doesn't really represent the result of a GET request. It is what you do inside the function that matters, so yes, if you do actually make a request, it will be made.

Comment: Note your own wording: "...a `Promise` that represents the **result** of a `GET` request..." I added emphasis to the key word there. The promise represents the result of the action, not the action itself.

Comment: I can only second @HereticMonkey. And notice that the promise is referenced through the `resolve` callback referenced from your running get request - that's the thing keeping the promise from being garbage-collected. Not the other way round. An active async request doesn't get stopped by "being garbage collected", in contrast it serves as a root object for GC.

Comment: @Bergi thank you for this in depth explanation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing an executor function to the promise constructor, i.e.:

```
new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { ... })
```

If that function gets called by the promise constructor (which, yes, it will be), then the rest has very little to do with whether you assign the promise object to anything. Your function has been called and it cannot be stopped, certainly not by a caller object going out of scope.

So, yes, your executor function is guaranteed to make progress.